# Pandoc grid table using cell data as the start number

Tags: pandoc

I've got a row in a table that is doing something I cannot explain and I can't find anything in the pandoc documentation that would explain it.

The row looks like this in markdown:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| SOME_VALUE     | `code`     | string     | MCI.          |
+----------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Pandoc with the grid table extension is outputting this:

```
<tr class="odd">
<td>SOME_VALUE</td>
<td><code>code</code></td>
<td>string</td>
<td><ol start="1101" type="I">
<li></li>
</ol></td>
</tr>
```

What is quite interesting is that MCI == 1101 in Roman numerals. So what is it that's trigging this? Why is Pandoc reading that cell data and using it as a list start value?

Comment: I think that it might be due to `someText. ` (including the space) being interpreted as list/enumeration. You could try escaping the `.` i.e. writing `MCI\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with grid tables.

```
MCI.
```

is treated by pandoc as a list marker (like `1.`) and the above outputs:

```html
<ol start="1101" type="I">
<li></li>
</ol>
```

See the [fancy_list](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fancy_lists) extension of pandoc flavoured markdown, which you can disable with `pandoc -f markdown-fancy_lists`.

Comment: Wow... thanks for that insight! I had no idea.